# How to find the Wallpaper URL in a project?

Tags: android

Sorry for messy title but here is my problem -
I have downloaded this project :- https://github.com/regalstreak/Wallpapers & trying to mess with it & i have added new things in it but i can't seem to find where did the developer added url of wallpaper sites i mean from where he is getting wallpapers i have checked whole project but i didn't find any url or any site. Can anyone please tell me the location & yes i have messaged him but he didn't replied yet.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the URL in the SplashScreen.java file at Line number 100.

url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/14nlvv");

If you run the URL in the next tab it will give JSON response.
You can find images in "wall_url" parameter in the response.